# ASP.NET Core POST hitting the wrong action

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I have a controller with the following actions

```
[HttpPost("training/create", Name="Create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateTrainingCommand command){
    // doing stuff ...
}

[HttpGet("training/createblankform", Name="CreateBlankForm")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateBlankForm(CreateBlankFormQuery command){
    // doing stuff ...
}

[HttpPost("training/createblankform", Name="CreateBlankForm")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateBlankForm(CreateBlankFormCommand command){
    // doing stuff ...
}
```

In my StartUp.cs file I am using `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute() and I have loaded a View that is loaded using the`CreateBlankFormGET` action.

The view contains a form that should be submitting to the `CreateBlankForm` `POST` action, but instead the `Create` `POST` action is getting hit.

I have tried configuring the form in a few different ways;

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" contenteditable="" asp-controller="Training" asp-action="CreateBlankForm" method="post">
...
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Create" />
</form>
```

and

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" contenteditable="" asp-route="CreateBlankTrainingForm" method="post">
...
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Create" />
</form>
```

and

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/training/createblankform" method="post">
...
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Create" />
</form>
```

But all of these still hit the `CreateBlankForm` `POST` action. Why is this hitting the wrong controller?

Comment: The html button with type="submit" will submit the form and post to `CreateBlankForm` post action , do you have any javascript function which will trigger by submit button ?

Comment: @NanYu - yes this was the cause - a JavaScript "submit" handler had been created. If you want to submit an answer I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: Ok , i will leave a reply , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any JavaScript events that are handling the `submit` form action?

Comment: Yes, there was a generic JavaScript event handler (`$("#submit").click(function () {..}`) in a linked file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```html
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Create" />
```

to

```html
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Create" />
```

and also your specify wrong action name
it's shoud be

```
action="createblankform"
```

not

```
action="/training/createblankform"
```

Please let me know if you have any problem